# Count unique numbers in R and SQL

Tags: sql-server, r

I have a data which I use in both R and SQL Server. The problem is when I search the unique numbers  for a specific column in R it shows 222 and in SQL it returns 216. What's the problem that caused this difference?

The query  used in SQL:

```
Select count(distinct ColName) from TableName
```

And in R:

```
Length(Unique(DataframeName$Colname))
```

Comment: Could you specify the datatypes of those columns?

Comment: Could there be null values in this column?

Comment: `Length(Unique(` did you mean `length(unique(` ?

Comment: My main suspect right now is whitespace - sql server does a lot of trimming on its own.

Comment: There aren't lot of cases. I suggest to copy unique number from both and just compare which values do not have matches.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to say without the actual data, but R and SQL look at unique values differently. R (more to the point - `unique`) will treat NA and various sizes of *spaces* as unique values:

```
> unique(c("f","g","f","","  ",NA,NULL))
[1] "f"  "g"  ""   "  " NA 

> length(unique(c("f","g","f","","  ",NA,NULL)))
[1] 5
```

SQL will treat various sizes of *space* as being equal and non-unique:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255));
INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, LastName)
       VALUES (1, 'Rockwell'),(2,''),(4,'Cohen'),(5,' '),(6,'  ');

Select count(distinct LastName) from Persons
```

Will give the answer `3`

You can easily trim all trailing and leading whitespace with `str_trim` from the `stringr` library in R:

```
library(stringr)

a <- str_trim(c("f","g","f","","  ",NA,NULL))
unique(a)
[1] "f" "g" ""  NA
```

Comment: No need for extra package, `trimws(unique(c("f","g","f","","  ",NA,NULL)))`

Answer (score 0):

With the the package `library(sqldf)` in `R`, you can use a `SQL` query in `R`.

For example you can count unique numbers in R in this way:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf('select distinct count (ColName) as count,
ColName
from TableName
group by ColName')
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why.

Comment: Maybe, using the same instruction, gets the same result. 
Maybe it's just a formatting problem.